# How to import JavaScript files (fabric.js) in a vaadin Application

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, vaadin, fabricjs

I'm working on a Vaadin application which is using spring boot.
I want to use the fabric.js framework, but have not managed to import the files without running into Errors yet.

When trying to use the @JavaScript Annotation, I run into following Error:

> [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : ERROR in ./fabric.min.js
>
> [v-server-output] c.v.b.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker   : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jsdom' in 'C:\entwicklung\grw2_new\app-and-run\applications\grw\grw-desktop\frontend'

After trying it with a npm installation(https://vaadin.com/directory/component/niiyeboahfabric-canvas), I ran into a similar Error:

> [ERROR] ERROR in ../node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js
>
> [ERROR] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/.../node_modules/tunnel-agent'
> ...
> [ERROR]  @ ../node_modules/jsdom/lib/api.js
>
> [ERROR]  @ ./fabric.min.js

To avoid the jsdom Error I tried to import the file in a onAttach Method using `UI.getCurrent().getPage().addJavaScript("frontend/fabric.min.js");`
But Vaadin does not manage to find the specified file, whether I put them in the frontend folder of my project or in META-INF/resources/frontend.

Comment: I do not know enough of `fabric` nor `vaadin`, but  the problem seems to be the way you choose to integrate the library. Does the following work: https://www.unpkg.com/browse/fabricjs@1.0.0/index.js when you include that?

Comment: Please be specific, how you have added the library. There are very few packages out there, that don't have _any_ deps. So simply downloading and placing it in `frontend` is very unlikely to "just work". Use `@NpmPackage` or manually tune your build-tool-config.